# Wifi stops working after 10 minutes

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

I don't know why, but on my Windows 7, my wifi stops working after about 10-30 mins, and the computer goes very slow! I don't know what that is, but I think it's a virus.

**Note**: I have dual-booted Win7 with Ubuntu 12, and this *only* happens on Windows

Comment: Use your normal procedure to verify if you have a virus.  Without additional information we cannot help.  Your WiFi disconnecting is unlike the caused by a virus.  Your computer being slow ( depending what you mean exactly ) could be.

Comment: Shall I use Hitman Pro or AVG? What's the best?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Answer (score 1):

Probably a issue with the driver of your wifi adapter. Update to the most recent driver from your manufacturer's website. If there is no newer driver, reinstall the current one by deleting the wifi adapter via device manager letting windows reinstall it after a reboot.